# Evince sees files that all other tools (shell, Nemo) do not see

Tags: files, filesystem, evince

I've opened a pdf file (~/Downloads/f1040x.pdf), filled the form and saved the filled form with a new name alongside the original form.

The problem is that I can only see that file through Evince (Open/Save dialogs). I cannot see it from terminal. I can "Copy file location" and it gives me the expected path, but `ls -la` says the file does not exist.

What's happening here?
Does Evince save files to some hidden overlay filesystem?

P.S. This reminds me of the Windows Vista's UAC and the virtual filesystem overlay for low-priviledge applications. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681

Comment: Did you open the file using `sudo`? does your shell follows special `umask` as its default permissions? what is the output of `sudo ls $HOME/Downloads/`? can you see your file in the output?

Comment: I opened the file by clicking the downloaded file button in Chrome. I cannot see the file when I run `sudo ls $HOME/Downloads/`. `locate` cannot find it with or without `sudo` (locate is often unreliable though). `

Comment: I've found the root cause. That was an internal solution that was wrapping Evince in Bubblewrap wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause:
An in-house security handler that was wrapping Evince in [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap).